# S3 bucket tagging with Python Boto "InvalidArgument"

Tags: amazon-s3, tags, boto, bucket, ceph

I have a problem with setting tags to S3 buckets with Python Boto.
I`m connecting to my own Ceph-storage and try this:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(
            aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
            host=RGW_HOST,
            port=RGW_PORT,
            is_secure=RGW_SECURE,
            calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
)
new_id = '10'
bucket = conn.get_bucket(new_id)
tag_set = TagSet()
tag_set.add_tag(key='a', value='b')
tags = Tags()
tags.add_tag_set(tag_set)
bucket.set_tags(tags)
```

But I have a error:

```
    boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><BucketName>ipo36</BucketName><RequestId>tx000000000000000000035-005ac4c3cf-1063bb-default</RequestId><HostId>1063bb-default-default</HostId></Error>
```

Anyone know what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These days I would recommend using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) rather than boto 2.

Here's some code that works:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
tag={'TagSet':[{'Key': 'Department', 'Value': 'Finance'}]}
response = client.put_bucket_tagging(Bucket='my-bucket', Tagging=tag)
```

Comment: Sorry, with boto3 i've had this error:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: Unknown

Comment: It worked for me! Try updating to the latest version: `sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade`

Comment: Can you try it from another computer, just to determine whether it is computer or network related?

Comment: I have all ceph-cluster elements on VM's on my PC. Maybe my problem in ceph-cluster configuration?